# How can I edit crontab in file?

Tags: linux, cron

I'm already using crontab, accessing it with "crontab -e" command and it works just fine. It would be great on my case to edit the cron directly in the file, so I'm trying to use the file located in /etc/crontab directory, but for some reason the cron jobs wont execute (just a dummy job).

I tryied to change the permissions or create files in /etc/cron.d but keeps not working.

This is my cron file:

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin

 

* * * * * root echo "123" > /home/ubuntu/test.txt
```

The two first lines was already in the file, so I didn't change that.

Comment: If you want to run cronjob as a root, edit root's crontab: `sudo crontab -e`.

Comment: @KazikM actually, I want to edit direct the file, not by a command.

Answer (score 0):

Users crontab files are located in this directory `/var/spool/cron/crontabs`, so you can edit the file you want directly from there

Comment: I tried to edit this file, but the cron jobs that is running in it, stop working. And at the beginning of the file has a warning saying "DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE". A funny fact is that I tryed to do the same thing (editing the /etc/crontab) in another virtual machine, and just works fine.

Answer (score 0):

But if you want to edit an existing crontab and delete a particular cron job, you can use the dd option after crontab -e. Suppose, there are 3 old cron jobs set up for different 3 different scripts to run. And, you want to delete one of the cron jobs out of three. You have to use the dd option to delete that specific cron job.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).